# How do I change iOS settings to "not" sync notes over the air with iCloud

Tags: iphone, ios

I first unchecked "notes" in settings, iCloud.  That didn't change anything so eventually I deleted the iCloud account altogether.  That didn't change anything.  How do I set my phone to sync notes with Outlook on my PC and disable syncing notes over the air with iCloud?

Comment: If you dialed Notes syncing and the current notes remained in place, it means that the current Notes you see are stored locally. Did you try deleting them (of course if you don't want them anymore)?

Answer (score -1):

If you are being returned the following iTunes message (see screenshot below). Make sure to only have a single notes account called "On My iphone". You can access your iPhone notes account by opening the Notes app on your iPhone and tapping on "Accounts".

You can bring all of your iCloud notes to your "On My iPhone" account as per these directions: [How to transfer iCloud notes to "On My iPhone" account](http://iphone-contacts.over-blog.com/article-transfer-icloud-notes-to-on-my-iphone-account-117700082.html)

[image]